# Progress Bar in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, user-interface, progress

I have a training doc on Excel, with multiple sheets, showing multiple tasks that need to be done. On the home page (worksheet) I would like to show a progress bar showing the amount of tasks complete as a percentage. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible, [take a look](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/35064/excel-2013-create-progress-bars/):

Using Excel 2013’s conditional formatting features, you can create progress bars on your spreadsheets. Progress bars are used to graphically represent the advancement of the data. Essentially, you get a chart-like effect within the rows and cells themselves.

Below is an example of the setup that you should have before you start. I will use Cold/Hot as my demonstration. I also stretched the E cell to make the progress bar longer. This is done to see a more accurate bar, but this step is not a requirement. As you can see, I put the number 12 in the progress bar cell. This number will be the percentage of the bar that is shaded.

[image]

From the Excel ribbon, select Conditional Formatting and then Data Bars. Next, select More Rules..

[image]

Now, you should see a window which will allow you to create a new formatting rule. For this step, we want to adjust the settings as follows:

Type: Chose Number, both Minimum and Maximum.

Value: Set the Minimum value to 1 and the Maximum value to 100.

Finally, chose your color, and click OK.

[image]

f you have adjusted all of the previous settings correctly, you should now see a progress bar.

[image]

Comment: @stevehilton You are welcome! Fell free to mark this answer as accepted ;)